# Oracle: SQL not properly ended

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails

I am trying to run this sql query in grails. BUt getting the SQL not properly ended error.

```
def sessionFactory    
final session = sessionFactory.currentSession;
final  String query  = 'select count(A.id) from Artifact as A LEFT JOIN classification as C on (A.id=C.artifact_id) where C.id IS NULL';
final sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);

def totalunclass =  sqlQuery.with {
                            addEntity(Artifact);                            
                            }
```

Comment: try a semicolon at the end, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
final  String query  = 'select count(A.id) as ct from Artifact A 
                       LEFT JOIN classification C on (A.id=C.artifact_id)
                        where C.id IS NULL';
```

Oracle just don't like `AS` keyword for aliasing table names, so removing it.

Comment: It should return me the count right? But its Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 1157.

Comment: SQL queries do not currently support returning aliases

Comment: Sorry, am not a grails guy, did the SQL error go off now ?

Comment: You can still add an _alias_ to your `count()`